# Convert MUI react datagird from table view to Card View

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

We have recently purchased a datagrid component from MUI.com (https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/). Currently we have a requirement for viewing the table view into card view. Will that MUI datagrid supports card view as well.  I could read, DataTables (datatables.net) supports card view by default.  So please let us know whether MUI datagrid also support the same?

answer to my question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.